# Extend uniqueness of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a differential equation $(2-x)u''' + (2x-3)u'' - xu' + u = 0$ and found a basis of solutions $c_1 x + c_2 e^x + c_3 xe^x$. I know this is the general solution when $x \neq 2$ because of the uniqueness theorem (which requires the coefficient of $u'''$ be 1).

My question is if I can say this is the general solution for all $x$? Can the uniqueness theorem be extended to when $u'''$ doesn't have coefficient 1?

Comment: For standard ODE theory the given DE is singular at $x=2$, thus the domain for the existence theory excludes this line/plane. You can discuss piecewise solutions that have continuous derivatives when connecting over the singularity. Here with these basis solutions this is obviously no problem.

Comment: Can you say that a nth order linear ODE has at most $n$ independent solutions regardless of the coefficient of $y^{(n)}$?

Comment: This is trivial, as one single (non-zero) solution would make that statement true. You get a solution space of dimension $n$ over every time interval where all coefficients are continuous and the leading coefficient non-zero.